# i cant install libmagickcore-dev,libmagickwand-dev in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, versions, imagemagick

I tried to install them buy

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

it gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickcore-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install libmagickwand-6.q16-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-6.q16-dev      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-dev (= 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

pls, can anyone help me?

If I Run

```
sudo apt-cache policy libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev libmagickwand-6.q16-dev
libmagickcore-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2
  Version table:
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2 50
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11 50
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
libmagickwand-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2
  Version table:
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2 50
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11 50
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2
  Version table:
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2 50
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11 50
         50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: No @N0rbert it didn't work

Comment: I can't reproduce on fresh 20.04 LTS VM using default repositories. Please run `sudo apt-get update` and post output of `apt-cache policy libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev libmagickwand-6.q16-dev` to the question.

Comment: added in post pls check.

Comment: Looks normally. Try `sudo apt-get install aptitude` then `sudo aptitude install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev` . Post error output if any.

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked after updating some packages